# If the VIF is 2 then what is the value of correlation coefficient $R^2$

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, inference, multicollinearity

If variance inflation factor is 2 what is the value of correlation coefficient $R^2$?

$$VIF = \frac{1}{1-R^2}$$

Given $VIF =2$, then
is this calculation correct?

$$\begin{align}
2 &= \frac{1}{1-R^2}\\
2-2 \cdot R^2 &= 1\\
2-1 &= 2 \cdot R^2\\
1 &= 2 \cdot R^2\\
R^2 &= \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. Take the opportunity to take the [tour](
https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour), if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [how to ask](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and on [formatting help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and write down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the calculation is correct. 
$$VIF = \frac{1}{1-R^2} \ .$$

If $VIF = 2$, then $1 - R^2 = 1/2$, so $R^2 = 1/2$.

However, a pointer on the $VIF$: VIF of an independent feature $X_1 = \frac{1}{1-R^2}$, where $R^2$ is the coefficient of determination for the linear regression with $X_1$ as dependent and features $\{X_2, X_3, \ldots, X_n\}$ as independents, given $\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ constitute the overall independent features.

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. Take the opportunity to take the [tour](
https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour), if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [formatting help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and write down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) to make them easier to read. And sorry about my typo.